# Normalization with stats.boxcox - ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, normalization

I'm currently practicing normalization with the dataset from [Weather Conditions in World War Two](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/smid80/weatherww2).

The column whose value I'm trying to normalize is "Precip"(precipitation/mm).

It seems that I'm giving ndarray to `stats.boxcox()` as argument, but I'm confused how the dataframe I used became ndarray.

Precip's dtype is object, and it has str values 'T'. So I did some preprocessing in order to replace T with min value before normalization.
Here's the code:

```
weatherww2_data = pd.read_csv("../input/weatherww2/Summary of Weather.csv")
precip_data = pd.DataFrame(weatherww2_data.Precip)

# select rows whose column value is not T or 0
except_list = ['T', '0', 0]
excluded_precip_data = precip_data[~precip_data['Precip'].isin(except_list)]

# get min
min_precip_except_zero = excluded_precip_data.min(axis=0)

# replace T with minimum value
replaced_precip_data = precip_data.replace(to_replace='T', value=min_precip_except_zero)
```

And here's the code for normalization:

```
normalized_precip = pd.Series(stats.boxcox(replaced_precip_data)[0], name='Precip', index=replaced_precip_data.index)
```

And this line gives the error msg:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py in boxcox(x, lmbda, alpha, optimizer)
   1053     x = np.asarray(x)
   1054     if x.ndim != 1:
-> 1055         raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional.")
   1056 
   1057     if x.size == 0:

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional.
```

Any idea what can be the issue?

I checked shape of `replaced_precip_data['Precip']`, isn't it "1-dimensional"?
I suppose I misunderstand the concept of array dimension.

```
print(replaced_precip_data['Precip'].shape)

output> (119040,)
```

Comment: A 1d shape is displayed as `(119040,)`.  A dataframe is 2d, while a column of a frame, a Series, is 1d.  Technically that's talking about the `values`, the data of the frame and series.  The pandas objects also have index and columns arrays.

Comment: `replaced_precip_data['Precip']` is 1d, but that means `replaced_precip_data` is a dataframe, 2d

Comment: @hpaulj, I added ['Precip'] after `replaced_precip_data` in the normalizing code, and now I don't have the error in question. Instead I have `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. I'm assuming I need to convert str values into int. Right now, some values in Precipe are a string like 1.016. Should I scale data so that I can save float value(as for 1.016, 1016)?

Comment: you'll have to ask someone else about converting your pandas series to numeric dtype.

Comment: Okay, anyway thanks for your advice on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is how I am doing it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Pakistan_Largest_Ecommerce_Dataset.csv")

price = df['price']  // You can replace price with your column name
price_normalized = stats.boxcox(price)
```

and that's it.

Actually boxcox cannot take "negative values", and "0" (as it assumes them **negative** as well) so, as far as I can see you have tried to eliminate the zero but, the negative values are not handled. So that, could be the problem. Converting your column to a Series is not solving the problem for this reason.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, I didn't feel that it might require further comments, that's why but, as you have asked so, I have added the details as per my knowledge.